# SAT in presence of a propositional theory

Tags: sat, sat-solvers

Is there a name for the SAT solving scenario where part of the formula is static (forming a propositional "theory") and serves as a static context for testing the satisfiability of relatively small sentence.

Many such tests need to be performed with different sentence, so evaluating the conjunction each small formula with the static part every time anew is suboptimal.

In contrast to incremental SAT, satisfiable sentences are not appended to the theory, but discarded after testing.

Is there a tool that could be adapted for such a case?

Comment: If SAT solvers are designed in a somewhat similar fashion to SMT solvers, then the incremental design should allow one to both `push` and `pop` formulas from the stack. Thus incremental SAT would still be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has an official name, but in the SMTLib parlance it is known as `check-sat-assuming`. See Section 4.2.5 (page 64) of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

Comment: It should be worth noting that `check-sat-assuming` takes as argument a list of boolean literals, which means that the associated clauses must already be in the environment prior to invoking this command and will not be automatically discarded when it returns. So *IMHO* the answer for a throw-away context is still `push`+`pop` combination, that is, incremental SAT/SMT solving. As opposed to what the OP seems to assume, incremental satisfiability does not only allow one to add clauses on the formula stack, but to remove them too.. so it fits perfectly to his own needs.